# Best practice on fetching data when using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to ask what is best practice in following case.
Imagine situation below:

```
 <Route path='/search/:term?' render={(props) => {
                return (<ProductList
                   items={this.state.DataFromAPI}
                   {...props}
                   />)
              }} />
```

What happens above is that imagine I had a search button somewhere. **When user clicked the search button** I would:

1) get data from API and store in `this.state.DataFromAPI`

2) Also change URL to "/search/someTerm" programatically

Now you can guess what would happen. Data would arrive from step 1, and also the respective component (in this case ProductList) would be rendered by router thanks to step 2 and ProductList would get needed data using props as on the code snippet.

However, there is a problem now.

If user directly types in browser the URL "/search/someTerm" the data fetching doesn't happen anymore.
This is clear because as I said previously data fetching would happen **when user clicked button** and I would pass the data as props to the route. Since there is no click, neither there is data fetching.

So what to do in such case when I want data to be loaded also when user types the URL?
I suppose component - in this case ProductList - should itself request data?

Comment: React is based on `State`, keep that in mind and it becomes very simple,.. So the best practice here is inside your `ComponentDidMount`, grab your data using whatever api your using, once you have the data, either use `setState`, or if you want to use `props`, use `forceUpdate`..

Comment: @Keith So you are suggesting to fetch data in componentDidMount of ProductList? (instead of fetching data on button click as I was doing before)

Comment: Yes, I would.. You could then have `fetching data`, or something like that on your initial render,..  And of course everything is then encapsulated inside `<ProductList>`

Answer (score 0):

I imagine scenario that you want to make sure that there is searched data when the ProductList rendered.

What I'm suggesting is:

1. Pass the api-method(from which you are requesting the data in parent
   component) to the product list.
2. Now in ProductList componentDidMount method check: if it doesn't get the appropriate data in props then call the method with
   getting    the search query from location search.
3. When api-request method set the state in parent component then the child will get re-rendered as required

.